# Making networks in Python

Tags: python, networkx

I want to make a partial duplication model such that I start out with s >= 1 vertices in graph G. Then introduce a new vertex "v" and choose a vertex "u" in **G** randomly. With probability **q**, connect **v** and **u**. Independently of each other, connect each neighbour of u to v with probability **p**. And I am suppose to repeat this depending upon my **s**.

I have a text file which has three columns: Protein1, Protein2 and Combined score. This file has more than 1000 such entries. Each line thus represents an edge in the graph going from "protein1" to "protein2" with weight "combined_score". I am using this file to implement the algorithm (mentioned above). I am filtering out only those lines where my combined_score is greater than 990.

```
4932.Q0010  4932.Q0017  951
4932.Q0010  4932.Q0032  951
4932.Q0010  4932.Q0045  313
4932.Q0010  4932.Q0085  263
4932.Q0010  4932.Q0105  410
4932.Q0010  4932.Q0143  930
```

The code:

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def partial_duplication_model(G,p,q,s,max_score):

    k=G.number_of_nodes()
    list=[]

    for i in range(s):
        #random.randint(1,k)
        node = random.choice(G.nodes())
        if node not in list:
            v = max_score + i
            G.add_node(v)
            list.append(node)

            G.add_edge(v,node,weight = q)

        #for j in range(k):
            for j in G.neighbors(node):
                if not j==v:
                    G.add_edge(j,node,weight = p)


    print(G.number_of_nodes())

    return(G)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        f=open("4932.protein.links.v10.txt","r").readlines()
        G=nx.Graph()
        max_score=0

        for x in f[1:]:
                y=x.split(" ")
                for node in y[:1]:
                        if int(y[2])>=990:
                                G.add_node(node)
                if int(y[2])>=990:
                        G.add_edge(y[0], y[1], weight=int(y[2]))
                temp=int(y[2])
        #print(type(temp))
                max_score=max(max_score,temp)

        p = 0.3
        q = 0.7
        s = 2
        res = partial_duplication_model(G,p,q,s,max_score)
        print("making a plot")
        stuff = nx.degree_histogram(res)
        plt.loglog(stuff)
        plt.show()
        #print("Average shortest path length : " , nx.average_shortest_path_length(res))`
```

This code is not working because when I try to compute average shortest path length, it says that graph is not connected.

Comment: A note: avoid naming your variables `list`, `str`, or other pre-defined identifiers. This way you shadow the pre-defined things, and an innocuous expression like `list(something)` may end up in a cryptic-looking error.

Answer (score 0):

- First thing I would do is get rid of single letter variable names.
- Shortcut: if you add an edge where a node doesn't exist, it will add the node.
- You can't use list as a variable.  (ok you can but don't expect good results)

  ```
  import networkx as nx
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import random

  def partial_duplication_model(G,p,q,s,max_score):
      k=G.number_of_nodes()
      my_list=[]

      for i in range(s):
          #random.randint(1,k)
          node = random.choice(G.nodes())
          if node not in my_list:
              v = max_score + i
              G.add_edge(v,node,weight = q)   # I don't understand what you are doing here.
              list.append(node)

          #are you sure your spacing is correct in the next 5 lines?    
          #for j in range(k):
              for j in G.neighbors(node):
                  if not j==v:
                      G.add_edge(j,node,weight = p)


      print(G.number_of_nodes())
      return(G)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      G= nx.Graph()
      max_score = 0
      with open('4932.protein.links.v10.txt','r') as f:
          for x in f.readlines()[1:]:
              node1, node2, val=x.split(" ")
              val = int(val)
              if val>=990:
                  G.add_edge(node1, node2, weight=val)
              max_score=max(max_score,val)
              p = 0.3
              q = 0.7
              s = 2
              res = partial_duplication_model(G,p,q,s,max_score)
              print("making a plot")
              stuff = nx.degree_histogram(res)
              plt.loglog(stuff)
              plt.show()
              #print("Average shortest path length : " , nx.average_shortest_path_length(res))
  ```